# Populate ListView from an Arraylist<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, hashmap, adapter

I have an `ArrayList<HashMap<Contact, Name>>` and I want to populate a ListView with it. What type of adapter can I use and what do I put in the `from` field of my adapter? Example below:

```
String[] from = ?
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.contact, R.id.name});
adapter = new KindOfAdapter(this, R.layout.row, from, to)
```

Hope it is clear. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

**1.  Implement BaseAdapter**

I think your best bet is to extend BaseAdapter and implement the following methods:

```
getCount()
getItem(int)
getItemId(int)
getView(int, View, ViewGroup)
```

It would look something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter() {
   private List<Map<Contact, Name>> map;
   private Context context;

   public MyAdapter(List<Map<Contact, Name>> map>, Context context) {
      this.map = map;
      this.context = context;
   }

   public int getCount() {
      return map.size(); // or do you want one list item per name?
      // if so, just count out all the map entries in each item of the list
   }

   public int getItemId(int position) {
      return position; // doesn't matter too much...
   }

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // populate the view here...
      // use LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource, parent, false) to inflate new views
   }
}
```

**2.  Be scrupulous about using the ViewHolder pattern**

When implementing getView(), utilizing this design pattern will save a LOT of memory:

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7767

Comment: This kind of makes sense, but I'm trying to understand the population process. How does getView() get the data for each row from my HashMap? And shouldn't I also implement newView()? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look at the position argument passed in to the getView() method.  You can directly access the data off of the stored List then.  You do not need to implement newView().

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayAdapter> - ArrayAdapter is designed to be used with ArrayLists (and arrays[]), although it doesn't support View binding you only have to override getView()